# How to load SVG nodes in HTML Page?

Tags: html, svg

I have one HTML5 Page and multiple files that declare nodes (elements) of an SVG Image.
The files look like this:

```
<g class="background">
    <g class="bg_path_a">
        <path d="M0 40 L21 40" />
    </g>
    <g class="bg_path_b">
        <path d="M42 21 L63 0 100 0 M23 40 L48 15" />
    </g>
    <g class="bg_path_c">
        <path d="M53 40 L100 40 M21 40 L53 40" />
    </g>
    <g class="bg_lockpath">
        <path d="M21 40 L33 40" />
    </g>
    <g class="bg_label">
        <rect x="0" y="20" width="10" height="10" />
    </g>
</g>
```

No xmlns, DTDs are declared, and they should remain like that. Now I want to be able to load such files but display them as SVG images in the HTML5 page, all should run on client side, no server side scripting is allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script>
function createXMLHttpRequest()
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // Firefox and others
  {
   return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) // Internet Explorer
  {
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  else
  {
    alert("XMLHttpRequest not supported");
    return null;
  }
}

function fixSVG()
{
    var svgElement, xmlHTTP, svgDoc
    xmlHTTP = createXMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHTTP.open("GET", "BadSVG.svg", false);
    xmlHTTP.send();
    svgDoc = xmlHTTP.responseText;
    svgElement = document.getElementById("yuck");
    svgElement.outerHTML = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'" +
            " width='" + svgElement.width + 
            "' height='" + svgElement.height + "'>" +
            svgDoc + "</svg>";
}
</script>
[...]
<body onLoad="fixSVG()">
[...]
<embed id="yuck" src="" type="image/svg+xml"
    width="500" height="500" wmode="transparent"/>
```

Tested only in Firefox...

Synchronous load of the file shouldn't be an issue if your files are small, as you shown.

[EDIT] Little improvements: avoid loading the file twice (empty `src` in the `embed` tag), and use the dimensions of the `embed` element in the declaration.

Comment: This is of course a nice solution, and apparently it solves the namespace issue I saw, too!

Comment: Hmm, I am testing with Chrome ver. 23, and I get the " Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP" when the broswer tries to execute xmlHTTP.send(); in function fixSVG(), may be if i set up a server this would be solved...but is there a solution that is completely Client Side based?

Comment: Yes, Chrome doesn't want to do XHR with the file: protocol, I saw the same issue, and once I ran a server and used localhost, the issue was gone. Firefox isn't as picky... I don't understand the "completely Client Side based" question, it is already all "client side based", ie. it doesn't involve a server-side script, only using a server to... serve files.

Comment: sorry for being unclear, I meant that I dont want to set up a server, I want the user to be able to use the page and choose the files to load without any server..but if I run chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files then it works fine, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The main problem seems to be getting the SVG snippet into the SVG namespace. You could use XSLT to "complete" the SVG (adding the surrounding svg element) and putting everything in the right namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0">

  <!-- The dimension can be supplied using a parameter.
       This defaults to 100%. -->
  <xsl:param name="width"  select="'100%'"/>
  <xsl:param name="height" select="'100%'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <svg version="1.1" width="{$width}" height="{$height}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|text()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You'd have to load the stylesheet and your SVG snippets using AJAX

Use AJAX to fetch the SVG snippet, like:

```
var loadXML = function(fileName,mime) {
  xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xmlHttpRequest.open("GET",fileName,false);
  xmlHttpRequest.send("");
  return xmlHttpRequest.responseXML;
}
var svgSnippet = loadXML(snippetURL,"image/svg+xml")
var xslt = loadXML(xsltURL,"application/xslt+xml")
var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslt);
// You can override the default width/height parameters here
xsltProcessor.setParameter(null,"width","150px")
xsltProcessor.setParameter(null,"width","90px")
// In the document there must be some element to append the SVG
documentGetElementById("svgContainer").appendChild(xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(svgSnippet,document).firstChild)
```

This is all untested, but maybe something to start from. In case you also need the XLink namespace, this is of course incomplete anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use jQuery, you may want to check out [Keith Wood's SVG plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html). I've used it before and it's very versatile.

If you check out the "Load" tab on the documentation page, it describes how you can load an external file and add it to an existing SVG.